# Why is this MYSQL statement giving me an error?

Tags: mysql, database, linux, unix, permissions

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/myuser/myproject/power/ids-ads.txt' INTO TABLE ids_ads  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

ERROR 29 (HY000): File '/home/myuser/myproject/power/ids-ads.txt' not found (Errcode: 13)
```

The file is there. I even pasted the path into the mysql console. The permissions are correct.

In fact, I even tested it on root user and root mysql.

```
-rw-r--r--   1 myuser myuser  15893 2010-12-26 20:56 ids-ads.txt
```

Comment: Are the files on the same machine ? Not a mount or anything like that?

Comment: Just one machine. very simple setup

Comment: And no spaces in the project name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that when you do LOAD DATA INFILE, MySQL is looking for that file on the *server* - not on your client machine.

If you want to use LOAD DATA INFILE to load a file that is on the client machine (and not the server machine), you must use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 2):

From the MySQL manual:

```
For security reasons, when reading text files located on the server, the files
must either reside in the database directory or be readable by all. Also, to use
LOAD DATA INFILE on server files, you must have the FILE privilege. For non-LOCAL
load operations, if the secure_file_priv system variable is set to a nonempty
directory name, the file to be loaded must be located in that directory.
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...probably a stupid question, but are there any invisible characters in the string '/home.../ids-ads.txt'?

Comment: I don't think so. it seems pretty regular text.

Answer (score 0):

As Marc B said, the file needs to be in the database directory or readable by all.  Not only does the file need to be readable, but MySQL needs permissions to read into the directory where the text file is stored.  What are the permissions on /home/myuser/myproject/power/ and its containers up to /home/myuser?  If, at any point in that chain, permission would be denied, then MySQL won't be able to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using phpmyadmin be sure to Enable `Use LOCAL keyword`. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If data is at your local machine, Please use below code it is working fine.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/home/cloudera/Data/ChurnDataFinal.csv"
INTO TABLE Customer_Churn
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```